# Send whole array as one post parameter using CURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I have array and I need send this array using post request.

I serialize this array as string and I need sent whole array as one post parameter.

I use for this CURL, this is index.php code:

```
  $name = array(2,3,"5.5");

  $name  = serialize($name);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.com/retrieve_post.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'name='.$name);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0') );
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

and this is `retrieve_post.php` file:

```
$arr = unserialize($_POST['name']);

$hand = fopen("test.txt", "w+");

if (is_array( $arr )) {
    fwrite($hand, "This is array");
}
else {
    fwrite($hand, "Not array");
}
fclose($hand);
```

Problem is that, after `unserialize($_POST['name'])` , I obtain not array.

In `test.txt` file is writed: "Not array".

Why, `$arr` has not array type? where I am wrong?

Comment: Would you mind to `print_r($_POST)` to either screen or file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `implode` instead of serialize.

```
$name = implode(',', $name);
```

And in the other file you can try `explode`.

```
$arr = explode(',', $_POST['name']);
```

Comment: I need sent multidimensional array, So implode is not optimal variant in this case...